# Set OnUnhandledKeyEventListener on Android

Tags: android, keyevent, android-12

Android 12 has issues with detecting inputs from a custom controller.  So I want to custom map them.

I want to detect key press, and I want to use `OnUnhandledKeyEventListener`, I have tried using different listeners like `OnGenericMotionListener` and they come with a `set` corresponding to them so that they can be attached; like `setOnGenericMotionListener`.

I cannot find such a `set` method for `OnUnhandledKeyEventListener`, so how do I attach this?

It shows `Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnUnhandledKeyEventListener'` when I try to write it in the IDE.

What can I do to attach such a listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `setOnUnhandledKeyEventListener` for this, rather we need to use  `addOnUnhandledKeyEventListener`. Works flawlessly!